# Updating backed array in Ember.js rc1 does not propogate to view

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to upgrade a partially built UI to the latest Ember.js rc1 and it has turned into a very big rewrite job thanks to the dramatically changed API. Most info out there (and here) has been rendered useless. I've had to go through the documentation again several times to get things partially working but there are a lot of loose ends. Here is a biggie. The views do not update like they did under the previous version. I'm missing something that must have to do with rerender, {{outlet}} or something else that I'm not aware of. The ember guides seem to need updates.

The template is very simple:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <button {{action "addOne"}}>add one</button>
  <ul>
  {{#each item in controller}}
    <li>{{item.title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

When clicked, the button adds a new element to the backed array. The console logs show that the array is growing, but the template does not change. [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayoung/RLmPk/) to illustrate how far I've gotten. Can anyone figure out what needs to be added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your example to highlight the fact when we use arrays in Ember, that we are using Ember arrays (`Ember.A()` or `Em.A()` if you want to make explicit this fact). From my understanding, you can use the methods `Em.A().addObject` and `Em.A().removeObject` to achieve the basic functionality using the Ember.Object getter and setter methods, (i.e. `.get()` & `.set()`) .

In order be properly observed by the Ember application, it is important to use the Ember getters and setters.

[A modified version of your fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/logicalhan/sVBCj/1/)

Comment: You're correct that addObject and removeObject must be used, but the [] syntax for arrays can still be used. From the docs for Ember.Array:

   `This module implements Observer-friendly Array-like behavior. This       mixin is picked up by the Array class as well as other controllers, etc. that want to appear to be arrays.`

Comment: @martinS_ Yes I am finding this out myself, and makes the Em.A reasonably convenient... but I'm confused as to how this worked in pre-RC1 Ember.js. The vast majority of (now unusable) examples out there use standard arrays. I'm too busy to do the experiments to find out, especially if I risk cluttering my brain up with obsolete APIs.

Comment: @martinS yeah, I realize that you can use the [] syntax, but using the Em.A() syntax helps to make it explicit, which I personally prefer.. It also gives notice to other people reading the code that something funny is going on with the arrays, which can be helpful.

Comment: @AliceYoung I think the array stuff worked essentially the same in pre2-pre4 as it does in ember-1.0.0.rc1, but I could be mistaken. I haven't messed around with the older stuff so I can't be much help to you there. As for obsolete APIs, yeah it can feel that way (especially with the way ember has been changing) but I think that the concepts bleed through, which does make them worth learning, but that's just how I feel about it..